# Como excluir elemento de uma lista em R

Tags: r

Tenho essa list:

```
x = list(1, 3, 5, 8, 13)
```

Como faço para excluir o segundo elemento?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outra forma que serve para qualquer objeto do R, e não somente listas, é não selecionar o elemento que você quer remover e atribuir de volta ao objeto original:

```
x <- x[-2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Conforme a [documentação de `R`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-set-components-of-a-list-to-NULL_003f), basta atribuir nulo ao elemento que deseja remover:

```
x[[2]] <- NULL
```